# How can I store data (from my HTML page) to SOLR file system using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, apache, solr, lucene

I have a form on my HTML page. I want to store information in solr file system so that I can do a query on it later on. How can I achieve this. How do I configure SOLR in that way? Please help me out.

This is the data I want to post:

> clinic_inf = {
>                                   "clinic_synched":false,
>                                   "location_synched":false,
>                                   "name":nameOfClinic,
>                                   "address":addressOfClinic,
>                                   "city":city,
>                                   "pin":pin,
>                                   "phone":phoneNumber,
>                                   "mobile":mobileNumber,
>                                   "email":emailOfClinic};

I tried doing a post server call using `$.post("http://localhost:8080/solr/example/update", clinic_inf, this._test);`. Below is the finction `_test`:

```
_test: function(response){
      console.log("successfull!");
 }
```

The error I am getting is:

> jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4 POST `http://localhost:8080/solr/example/update` l.cors.a.crossDomain.send
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8080/solr/example/update`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: Solr is a document search engine, and not really a "file system" in any way. What have you tried? You're usually better off by using Solr for what it's good at - searching large amounts of information. For storing information from a HTML form, just using a regular RDBMS is usually a better choice.

Comment: I am sorry for calling it a file system and thanks to correct me. I want to use solr since I have been asked to do so by my instructor. I have configured the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml as well. Then I tried calling [http://localhost:8080/solr/update/] using $.post like this : `$.post("http://localhost:8080/solr/", clinic_inf, this._test)` from the jQuery script I used where `clinic_inf` is the json object I want to store and `this._test` is the callback function I am using which does nothing but `console.log("success!")`. Later, I want to search on the same data, may be a full text search.

Comment: Please add these details to your question, together with your schema and what you're posting. Your URL should also include the name of your collection / core (`/solr/foo`). Also remember that Solr should not be exposed to the general internet (including browsers through Javascript).

Comment: I added the details. @MatsLindh